# Can I get sensible labels for lm-sensors output for "applesmc-isa-0300"?

Tags: 11.10, macbook, sensors

2011 8,3 Macbook Pro running 64bit 11.10.

When I run `sensors` from the `lm-sensors` package, I get a *lot* of information, but no way to understand it:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +53.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +53.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +52.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +50.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +49.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

applesmc-isa-0300
Adapter: ISA adapter
Left side  : 2001 RPM  (min = 2000 RPM)
Right side : 2001 RPM  (min = 2000 RPM)
TB0T:         +33.2°C  
TB1T:         +33.2°C  
TB2T:         +29.0°C  
TC0C:         +52.8°C  
TC0D:         +47.2°C  
TC0E:         +51.8°C  
TC0F:         +53.0°C  
TC0J:          +1.0°C  
TC0P:         +44.5°C  
TC1C:         +52.0°C  
TC2C:         +52.0°C  
TC3C:         +52.0°C  
TC4C:         +52.0°C  
TCFC:          +0.2°C  
TCGC:         +51.0°C  
TCSA:         +52.0°C  
TCTD:          +0.0°C  
TG0D:         +44.5°C  
TG0P:         +43.2°C  
THSP:         +37.5°C  
TM0S:         +57.5°C  
TMBS:          +0.0°C  
TP0P:         +50.0°C  
TPCD:         +55.0°C
```

The core temp info is really useful and I'm pretty sure that `Left/Right Side` refers to the two fans within, but otherwise, I have no idea what this information means.

Is there something I can use to normalize this information?

Comment: [This page](https://superuser.com/questions/553197/interpreting-sensor-names) contains the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install some additional software to get the MacBook to do what you want. the [Ubuntu Wiki page here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-1/Natty#Sensors) provides you all the info you need but essentially;

- Add coretemp to the list of modules loaded during the boot process.
- It is highly recommended to use the fan controller daemon that is included in the mactel-support ppa called `macfanctl`

Comment: Already done ;)

Answer (score 0):

The codes you see in `sensors`' output are called SMC (System Management Controller) codes. From [Wikipedia's article for System Management Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller):

> The SMC has roles in controlling thermal and power management, battery charging, video mode switching, sleep and wake, hibernation, and LED indicators. It also enables enforcement of the macOS End User License, allowing macOS to identify when it is running on non-Apple hardware.

There is a similar question for the output of `sensors` on [Super User](https://superuser.com/): [Interpreting sensor names](https://superuser.com/questions/553197/interpreting-sensor-names)

From the ([now archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20160525201657/http://jbot-42.github.io:80/Articles/smc.html)) link that [ruief](https://superuser.com/users/197484/ruief) provided in [their answer](https://superuser.com/a/967056/1064914), you can find the following correspondence between the output of `sensors` and the meaningful names for most of the keys:

| `sensors` output | Meaningful key name |
| --- | --- |
| TB0T | Battery TS_MAX |
| TB1T | Battery 1 |
| TB2T | Battery 2 |
| TC0C |  |
| TC0D | CPU 1 Package |
| TC0E | CPU 1 |
| TC0F | CPU 1 |
| TC0J |  |
| TC0P | CPU 1 Proximity |
| TC1C | CPU Core 1 |
| TC2C | CPU Core 2 |
| TC3C | CPU Core 3 |
| TC4C | CPU Core 4 |
| TCFC |  |
| TCGC | PECI GPU |
| TCSA | PECI SA |
| TCTD |  |
| TG0D | GPU Die |
| TG0P | GPU Proximity |
| THSP |  |
| TM0S | Mem Module A1 |
| TMBS |  |
| TP0P | PCH Proximity |
| TPCD | PCH Die |